# Appium with Android Studio

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, appium

Does Appium with android studio needs uiautomator Viewer, Because Why i'm asking Here as a beginner I need To Know Appium  Installation having Two Methods "Eclipse with appium" And Advanced Method is Appium with Android Studio. UIAUTOMATOR need or Not. for Appium with Android Studio.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure of what you are asking, but if I understand correctly here is my answer:

I use Eclipse and Appium, and because the Android SDK plug-in for Eclipse has been deprecated, you need to install Android Studio to get the SDK.  You also need to install the Android Studio to get the UIAutomator, which you will find you absolutely need to have.  Once I installed the Android Studio, I've not had any need to actually use it as a development environment at all.  The UIAutomator can be invoked from a command line.

Answer (score 0):

it don't ned the uiautomator, you can use the inspector. so no need uiautomator if you want to set up the appium with the android studio.

if you are not using android studio then it needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending the element which you need to access while running the test case.

If you can not get elements then its necessary to find element by xpath

Its available in android-sdk/tools/bin.

Answer (score 0):

it's necessary to download android studio for appium as SDK plugin no longer available. 
so don't worry just set all path correctly.
i'm new too but with help of android studio i'm not receiving any error or problem related UIAutomator.